# populate utag_data (universal data object) values in adobe target

Tags: adobe, aem, tealium

I have Tealium `utag.sync.js` loaded with adobe target `at.js` and visitor api js.

Application populates bunch of app data into `utag_data (Universal Data Object)`

Can this data available in Adobe Target to define rules around the data , to define activities( segments), Experiences ?

Are there any configurations that I need to do to propagate the data from tealium to Target ?

Thanks,
Sri

Answer (score 2):

To start with there is a new version of the Adobe Target tag, currently in BETA, that is available for you to use, that will allow for data to be mapped from Tealium to Target.

If you would like to stick with having the full at.js in the utag.sync.js file, you will need to use one of the following target functions:

1. adobe.target.getOffer()

   - With this you will have to send a "fake" request for a mbox, passing in the data.
2. adobe.target.trackEvent()

   - Allows you to send an Event with data to Target. Using the mbox property as the event name.
3. window.targetPageParams()

   - Will allow you to append data to just the global mbox call request.
4. window.targetPageParamsAll()

   - Will allow you to append data to all requests going to Target

You will be able to use these functions within a JS extension where you can grab the current data object `b`, containing anything the utag has captured.

For more information on these calls, I would recommend reviewing the at.js documentation [here](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/target/ov2/cmp_at.js_Functions.html).

Comment: Thanks. I am new to Tealium and Target. Above javascript calls will be in tealium , correct ? I would like to use Targeting mode on an AEM page and personalize experience based on data available in tealium ( for example : latitude, longitude of place search populated in utag_data, which should be mapped to Target activity rule). I hope , i am clear on defining the use case.

Comment: I see following in https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/Tags/Test-amp-Target-Tag-Basic-Configuration/ta-p/13361

Mapping is not supported for the synchronous version of Test & Target.

Comment: @Sri That is correct only the new Async version supports full mappings.